# Pyspark - create our python package

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

In Synpase Notebook I've a separate notebook that contains all the functions that I need to run in another notebooks.

If I create a new notebook, for example, in first command I'll put

`%run ETL Functions` to use all the functions.

So for example inside that ETL notebook I can have this function:

```
def calculate_square(x):
    return x ** 2
```

and I want to create a package and insert for example this function and after I can do this:

```
from test_package import functions

result = functions.calculate_square(5)
print(result)  # Output: 25
```

so with that I don't need to run the ETL Function notebook every time I need to use a specific function.

My idea, but I don't know if it is possible, is to keep the ETL Functions notebook, and inside that notebook take the functions and insert them into the package and this package will be allocated to the cluster. That is, if I need to add another function, I just have to go to the notebook, insert the function and run the notebook separately and the function will automatically be available in the package. So I can also define different clusters and use this package in different clusters.

but I'm receptive to other ideas, this idea of ​​mine was more because version control and passing to different environments is easier, I think.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you already know how to create that package in Python, or you need help for that as well? I am asking because I want to write an answer.

Comment: If you can do that it would be great @ZiyaMertKarakas and I appreciate a lot your help

Answer (score 1):

With using only 2 notebook you cannot create package kind of functionality, but what you can do is write your custom functions to some `.py` file along with these 2 notebooks and import it.

You can follow below steps for it.
First, in **ETL** notebook add below code blocks.

```
%%sh
mkdir -p /synfs/user_pkg/
echo '''
    def calculate_square(x):
        return x ** 2
        
    def calculate_cube(x):
        return x ** 3
    ''' > /synfs/user_pkg/custscript.py
```

Here, I am adding these functions inside synapse filesystem.
Then by adding this path to system, you can import these functions.
Below is code for adding into system path.

```
import sys
if  "/synfs/user_pkg/"  not  in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("/synfs/user_pkg/")
print("Done")
print("Import functions from 'custscript'")
```

Add above code blocks as below in `ETL` notebook.

[image]

Then call it from another notebook only once.

```
%run ETL
```

and

```
from custscript import calculate_square
from custscript import calculate_cube

print(calculate_square(3))
print(calculate_cube(3))
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to insert any other function add that inside
`echo` command in **ETL** notebook and run it once.

Comment: Thanks a lot JayashankarGS, but in that case, I will always need to run at the beginning of each notebook that I create and use, this command %run ETL right ? basically that's what I'm doing at the moment, and I wanted to allocate the functions, and not need to run the notebook with the functions. If I created a new notebook the first command would be: from custscript import calculate_square... I don't need to run the notebook. But I don't know if is possible :\ once again thanks a lot !

Comment: you no need to run this `%run ETL` always only once it need to be run and if you done any alteration to custom function then only you need to run again.

Comment: If you want to use directly without running any command then you need to create `.py`
file and needs to upload it to storage account then add that path to system.

Comment: I tested your solution and working nice with %run ETL and after from custscript import calculate_square from custscript import calculate_cube print(calculate_square(3)) print(calculate_cube(3)), but if I create another notebook, and only execute this from custscript import calculate_square from custscript import calculate_cube print(calculate_square(3)) print(calculate_cube(3)) it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'etl_functions' that's why I asked, if I have notebook 1, 2 and 3 if I have to put %run ETL in each of them. Yes, the last approach that you said to upload it can be good

Comment: where you are creating this notebook? In the same workspace right?

Comment: right, in the same workspace. In short, I followed all your steps, created the ETL notebook and I ran it. After, I create another notebook and I executed %run ETL and ran functions, and ran it well. After I created another notebook, just with from custscript import calculate_square from custscript import calculate_cube print(calculate_square(3)) print(calculate_cube(3)) and it said that error: the module  is not found :\

Comment: @SPT sorry but  f you read the comments you'll understand that unfortunately I still don't have the solution of my problem

Comment: As i said for making it global like every notebook should have the package you need to make '.py' in storage account and in every notebook you need to mount it and add that path to system. Rather than doing it, it is better to use just `%run`.I will look any other possible way.

Comment: ok, but are there no other alternatives? ingest an external package into the cluster with the functions ? for example is it not possible to do this on the notebook to ingest the functions?

Comment: There is option for adding external packages from pypi, .jar,etc... but not for .py or custom files.

Comment: ok understood, I'll do some more research on other alternatives and hope there are more responses to this post. Thanks a lot again